# SlickGrid Dissapearing Text in Frozen Column on Horizontal Scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll, width, slickgrid

I'm encountering a weird issue with SlickGrid.

I have a grid with a size of 1000px by 500px which has a title column that is frozen (with the [JLynch7 branch](https://github.com/JLynch7/SlickGrid/tree/2.0-frozenRowsAndColumns)). This works fine.

If I have 17 columns instead of 16, then when I scroll to the right and then scroll down, the frozen title column cell text dissapears on some of the rows.

If I increase the size of the grid to 1100px by 500px, then 17 columns works fine and 19 columns recreates the issue.

It seems like this has something to do with the size of the grid and the columns, and SlickGrid only keep track of a certain number of cells or something like that.

Edit: Note that decreasing the width of each column has a similar effect as increasing the size of the grid

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed by incorporating following changes:-

Add d as five parameter to appendCellHtml in line 1947 inside SlickGrid.js in function "appendRowHtml".

```
    } else if (options.frozenColumn > -1 && i <= options.frozenColumn) {
      appendCellHtml(stringArrayL, row, i, colspan, d);
    }
```